# How to add organisation to the Drupal.org user profile?

Tags: community-official-site

When posting on the [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org), I'd like to attribute the contribution, however when I'm selecting it, the label says:

> X at organization `not applicable` for customer `not applicable`

When clicked on *not applicable* link, I've got tooltip that I should add organization on my user profile. However I already did that (in *Edit/Account/Work*) and it's set as *Current organization*. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but where is your profile on D.O? Just to do some extra checking and possibly refine my answer ...

Comment: It's [here](https://www.drupal.org/u/kenorb). If the case is to create new Organization, I don't feel the legal right to create such page for some large worldwide organisations (like PwC). What then?

Comment: I can understand your challenge to get approval for such organization, eg to find the right person to ask, and then get the actual approval. How about you create something anyway about that organization, but without mentioning their actual name, and only using information that is considered as not confidential?

Comment: Could be tricky to create organisation without mentioning the name. I think they're planning to agree on some legal process of contributing, but I don't know if that involves creating the organisation profile and it probably could take months or years I guess. Secondly would be tricky to find the right person who can make that happen. It would be great on d.o., if you can just select organisation just based on your provided list in the profile, less trouble. But anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: I agree with your prior comment. I just extended my answer to share some tricks I've used in the past 2 decades in similar situations (getting approval from a global bank to use them as a reference was a similar challenge ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example, have a look at my profile on D.O., which contains [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2461349).

So make sure you have a similar Organization created there, which you can do via [Create Organization](https://www.drupal.org/node/add/organization), which is the link you can also find on [Organizations](https://www.drupal.org/organizations).

If you're not the current owner (or something like that) of such organization, then you need to think of a way to get that Organization created around there. I don't remember any validation (when I registered the one I refer to), but what I would do:

1. Check with the organization you want to refer to if they are OK with getting such registration.
2. Have them complete such registration, or ask permission that you do it for them (and have them QA review it afterwards if needed).

If it's a huge organization, it may be a challenge to get approval from such organization, eg to find the right person to ask, and then get the actual approval. In that case, as an alternative, maybe you create something anyway about that organization, but without mentioning their actual name, and only using information that is considered as not confidential? But keep in mind that some companies may not want the world to know that they use Drupal ... eg for competitive reasons ...

Extra hint (for future occasions): try to make it part of contract negociations, something that they confirm that they are aware (and will not object) that you will register them as a company (if they are not yet registered). Possibly adding an appropriate annex to your contract with the details of that registration. It'll slow down contract negotiations, but that's probably the best moment to get approval. If needed offer them some kind of reduction on your rate to make them accept it. And of course, also explain the added value to them for being listed there (like free advertising?) ...

**Note**: there is also a [Marketplace FAQ](https://www.drupal.org/marketplace/guidelines/faq) which may give you more ideas to get an organization registered correctly.

Comment: @clive: sorry for our concurrent editing (and that I missed another quote). where on Drupal.SE is there any tool for collaborative editing?????

Comment: Probably there isn't one.

Comment: Not a problem, call it OCD on my part if you like @Pierre.Vriens ;) We don't have any such collaborative editing tool to the best of my knowledge, I think it's been asked for before on meta but the relative rarity of collisions meant is wasn't worth the dev effort to implement

Comment: Well, then maybe it should be possible to use the whatever technique that is in place already for stopping a 2nd "edit suggestion" if a prior one is waiting in the review que, which you can see with the edit link changed to something like edit (1) ... Anyway, wans't too hard this time to eyeball your edits and re-apply them. Time for my English dictionary now to go find out what OCD means ...

Comment: _OCD_ means _Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder_. What the dictionary would not tell you is that it is used to joke about what somebody does, especially when _putting something in order_. @Clive I am so OCD that I write _CDO_ instead of _OCD_. ;) (Sorry, I waited so long to make such a joke.)